# I have a Gateway 15.6 Ultra Slim Notebook AMD Ryzen 7 that I use for school and casual gaming occasionally; should I update my drivers?

Tags: laptop, drivers, windows-11, amd-ryzen

I wanted to download some games, but the website recommends that I update my driver and I wanted to know if updating the driver would be safe and not damage anything inside of my laptop.

[image]

[image]

<sup>full versions on clickthrough</sup>

Comment: You are asking us about an ad for an application that downloads drivers.  You already have the most updated display driver installed.

Comment: Don’t take the advice or random websites. Trust Stack Exchange and not random sites that say you should do something to get a “free” game.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore anything that tries to sell you anything by IOBit, or anything purporting to be a 'driver booster', 'game booster' or similar.

It's not quite malware, but it's cr@pwware.

If you want to check your GPU drivers, either trust the builit-in Windows updater, or go to the manufacturer's site - Intel, NVidia, AMD etc.

Answer (score 0):

NEVER follow advice on magic solutions for updating your drivers.
Trust in Windows to detect required driver updates.

Driver updater products are generally very dangerous - you risk
them installing incompatible drivers and ruining your setup.
Windows does it in a much more reliable way.

Wise words :
[If it ain't broke, don't fix it](https://www.bookbrowse.com/expressions/detail/index.cfm/expression_number/326/if-it-aint-broke-dont-fix-it).

Comment: Why downvote correct advice ? Some people apparently believe in driver updaters.